# Issues insttaling Cardano-node

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, install

I have followed instructions to install Cardano-node and cli ( cardano-node-1.33.0-linux) based on video instructions in https://hydra.iohk.io/build/9941151.

I've got an error:

```
trace: haskell-nix.haskellLib.cleanGit: /run/user/1001/build-9941151/cardano-node/source does not seem to be a git repository,
assuming it is a clean checkout.
main: line 82:  2996 Killed                  nix-build "${args[@]}" "${extraArgs[@]}"
```

After that I checked and found release 1.32

```
[nix-shell:~]$ cardano-node --version
cardano-node 1.32.1 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Any idea?
Thanks
Xavier

Comment: can you show us, where is your installation? please the output of this command. which cardano-node && which cardano-cli

Comment: Try this manual: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node

Answer (score 1):

Try this resource for installing the cardano-node it worked for me and it was very intuitive it goes through installations up to version 1.33.1 currently https://cardano-node-installation.stakepool247.eu/

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this :

1. check your ghc --version and use the version in the command below (compare the path, if you have the proper version.
2. with this command you can find where is cardano-cli .

find ~/git/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build -type f -name cardano-cli

3. here you can find where is your current 1.32.0 version

ps -Af | grep cardano-node

4. at the end, if you have ghc version(step 1., you will have the path where is the new version (step 2.),  then you type the next command correct

cp /home/{yourusername}/git/cardano-node/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.10.4/cardano-node-1.33.0/x/cardano-node/build/cardano-node/cardano-node ~/.local/bin/

i hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

So I checked and 1.33 properly instaled on linux, but after running nix-shell it goes back to 1.32.

It seems like nix-shell invokes git to look for 1.32

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent resource mentioned by @Floof99 there is another guide you may find useful if you intend to make use of other tools like the Signing API or DBSync:

- https://cardano-community.github.io/guild-operators/Build/node-cli/ - Comprehensive guide to getting a node built with additional tools